# D3 javascript - convert two text appendings to "loop"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to convert this two text appendings to one statement.

```js
var pResource_d3 = d3.select("g").append("text");

        pResource_d3
            .style("font-size" , "11px")
            .style("font-weight", "normal")
            .attr("x", 50)
            .attr("y", 10)
            .text("exampleText");
        
        pResource_d3 = d3.select("g").append("text")
          .style("font-size" , "11px")
          .style("font-weight", "normal")
          .attr("x", 200)
          .attr("y", 10)  
          .text("exampleText2");
```

I've tried this and i dont know why this doesn't works. What is missing here?

```js
var xValues = [50, 200];

       var pResources = d3.select("g");
       
            pResources.selectAll("text")
             .data(xValues)
             .enter()
                .append("text")
                .style("font-size" , "11px")
                .style("font-weight", "normal")
                .attr("x", function(d) {return d;})
                .attr("y", 10)
                .text("exaMPL");
```

**edit:**
this works also (only for testing - very bad practice):

```js
      var xValues = [50, 200];
      var pResource_d3 = null ; 
        for (let k = 0; k< xValues.length; k++) {

            pResource_d3 = d3.select("g").append("text");
                    pResource_d3
                     .style("font-size" , "11px")
                     .style("font-weight", "normal")
                    .attr("x", xValues[k])
                    .attr("y", 10)
                    .text("exampleText");
        }
```

Comment: One possible explanation is that you already have other text elements in that group. Try `pResources.selectAll(null).etc...`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thanks this works! You are right, the element contains already a text element.